# Connecting to my local mysql server host in pc having tow ethernet cards

Tags: c#, mysql, server, localhost, ethernet

I have one PC with two ethernet cards. One connected to LAN'A', the other is an Ethernet adapter (USB-RJ45) connected to LAN'B'.
I installed an MySQL SERVER and created a user : root@localhost(127.0.0.1).
I tried these three operations in local :

1. Connecting to MySQL server from Command Prompt using root@localhost and doing something (Select) with both Eth-Cards used  == OK.
2. Connecting to MySQL Server though a C# application with same user : root@localhost and with both Ethernet cards in use ========= NOT Allowed and exception of Authentication...
3. Disabling one of the Ethernet cards and trying same operation in case two ==== OK

My problem is: how can I connect to MySQL server via my C# application when both Ethernet cards are in use? (case 2).

Comment: root@localhost doesn't make sense, Because root can only access from the local system. Add a new user give him enough rights, ta create rows delete edit and so on and use this user with newuser@% or even better only with the diefferent ip ranges from a and b

Comment: I agree that was bad example for root@localhost and let's say I created what u said : someuser@localhost with some privileges... I'll try the different ip ranges suggestion tomorrow but for the % it's not secure for the client... thx

Comment: You have to allow user someuser  to access from outside the local computer so localhost isn't possible, because neither network card could access the server from any other computer.so for the first step to get the ball rolling you grant the someuser@% some rights see and read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html for more details